# Swap items of a linked list in pairs - revision 2

Tags: java, unit-testing, linked-list, interview-questions

The first revision is available [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/96871/23821) and the code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MaksimDmitriev/Reverse-LinkedList). I modified the method `reversePairs` and added `mSize` to convert my singly linked list to an array.

Now my main question is the following: do I test all possible types of input for this problem?

**SinglyLinkedList**

```
package com.reversell;

public class SinglyLinkedList {

    private Node mFirst;
    private Node mLast;
    private int mSize;

    public SinglyLinkedList(Node first) {
        this.mFirst = first;
        this.mLast = first;
        this.mSize = 1;
    }

    public SinglyLinkedList(int[] array) {
        if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.mFirst = new Node(array[0]);
        this.mLast = this.mFirst;
        mSize = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            addLast(new Node(array[i]));
        }
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return mSize;
    }

    public void addLast(Node node) {
        mLast.setNext(node);
        mLast = node;
        mSize++;
    }

    public Node getFirst() {
        return mFirst;
    }

    public Node getLast() {
        return mLast;
    }

    public void print() {
        Node current = mFirst;
        System.out.print("[");
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.print(current);
            current = current.getNext();
            if (current != null) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("]");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void reversePairs() {
        // The list is empty or contains one element
        if (mFirst == null || mFirst.getNext() == null) {
            return;
        }
        Node temp = null;
        Node fop = mFirst;
        mFirst = mFirst.getNext();
        while (fop != null && fop.getNext() != null) {
            if (temp != null) {
                // Set the next element of temp, where temp is the predecessor of fop.
                temp.setNext(fop.getNext());
            }
            // 12 -> 34 -> 88
            temp = fop.getNext(); // temp == 34
            fop.setNext(temp.getNext()); // 12 -> 88
            temp.setNext(fop); // 34 -> 12
            temp = temp.getNext(); // temp == 12
            fop = temp.getNext(); // fop == 88
            if (fop == null) {
                mLast = temp;
            } else {
                mLast = fop;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Unit tests.**

```
package com.reversell;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SinglyLinkedListTest {

    // The list is empty. We don't run the while loop in reversePairs
    @Test
    public void testEmpty() {
        int[] orig = new int[] {};
        int[] expected = new int[] {};
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        assertArrayEquals(expected, toArray(reverse(linkedList)));
        assertNull(linkedList.getLast());
    }

    // The list contains one element. We don't run the while loop in reversePairs
    @Test
    public void testSingleElement() {
        int[] orig = new int[] { 12 };
        int[] expected = new int[] { 12 };

        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        assertArrayEquals(expected, toArray(reverse(linkedList)));
        assertEquals(new Node(expected[expected.length - 1]), linkedList.getLast());
    }

    // The while loop is run once.
    // We leave the loop because fop is null. We don't go inside (temp != null)
    @Test
    public void testTwoElements() {
        int[] orig = new int[] { 12, 34 };
        int[] expected = new int[] { 34, 12 };

        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        assertArrayEquals(expected, toArray(reverse(linkedList)));
        assertEquals(new Node(expected[expected.length - 1]), linkedList.getLast());
    }

    // The while loop is run once.
    // We leave the loop because fop.getNext() is null. We don't go inside (temp != null)
    @Test
    public void testThreeElements() {
        int[] orig = new int[] { 12, 34, 78 };
        int[] expected = new int[] { 34, 12, 78 };

        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        assertArrayEquals(expected, toArray(reverse(linkedList)));
        assertEquals(new Node(expected[expected.length - 1]), linkedList.getLast());
    }

    // The while loop is run more than once.
    // We go inside (temp != null).
    @Test
    public void testFourElements() {
        int[] orig = new int[] { 12, 34, 78 };
        int[] expected = new int[] { 34, 12, 78 };

        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        assertArrayEquals(expected, toArray(reverse(linkedList)));
        assertEquals(new Node(expected[expected.length - 1]), linkedList.getLast());
    }


    private SinglyLinkedList reverse(SinglyLinkedList list) {
        list.reversePairs();
        return list;
    }

    private int[] toArray(SinglyLinkedList list) {
        int[] arr = new int[list.getSize()];
        Node node = list.getFirst();
        int index = 0;
        while (node != null) {
            arr[index++] = node.getData();
            node = node.getNext();
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first impressions:

- There is altogether too much code, and it's too confusing.
- Your `SinglyLinkedList` class should not expose `Node`s in its interface.
- If there is just one method to add a node to a singly-linked list, it should be `addFirst()` rather than `addLast()`.  (Manipulating the end of the list efficiently requires that you maintain an `mLast` pointer, which is an unnecessary complication.  Minimalism is crucial for interview situations.)
- Instead of `print()`, it would be more idiomatic to define `toString()`.

### "Raw" vs. "polished" linked lists

There are two styles of linked lists.

The simple kind exposes the list nodes as *the* interface.  For an example of this, see [Reversing k-sized sequences in a linked list](/a/43494/9357).  (This node-swapping question is a specific case of that problem where *k* = 2.)  The user just manipulates pointers as necessary.  There is no additional bookkeeping for, say, the size of the list.

In contrast, the [Java `LinkedList` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) presents a data structure where the nodes are an implementation detail that is hidden from the user.

What you have done, though, is a dangerous hybrid.  By accepting and returning `Node`s, you make is possible for other code to manipulate the node pointers behind your back, possibly rendering your `mLast` and `mSize` inconsistent.

Therefore, your method signatures should be designed such that they only accept and return `int`s, not `Node`s.

### Simplification

The problem can be solved without keeping track of `mLast` and `mSize`, so you should drop them.  Then you no longer need to worry whether `reversePairs()` sets `mLast` correctly.

You can **eliminate special cases by introducing a dummy node**.  In particular, a dummy node would let you get rid of the special handling for `array[0]` (and the special handling for an empty `array`).  It would also make it impossible for `mFirst` to be `null`, thus eliminating that special case from `reversePairs()`.

`fop` and `temp` aren't exactly variable names that make sense.  `temp`, in particular, is almost always a horrible name that can be improved.  In my solution below, I've defined `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` up front for each iteration, and it's very simple to just adjust their `next` pointers.

```
public class SinglyLinkedList {
    /** Dummy node */    
    private final Node head = new Node(0);

    public SinglyLinkedList(int[] array) {
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            this.addFirst(array[i]);
        }
    }

    public void addFirst(int datum) {
        Node n = new Node(datum);
        n.setNext(this.head.getNext());
        this.head.setNext(n);
    }

    public void reversePairs() {
        // For each loop iteration, transform
        //
        //                    maybe null --+
        //                                 |
        //                                 v
        // Original: (a) ->  b  ->  c  ->  d ...
        // To:        a  ->  c  -> (b) ->  d ...
        //                          ^
        //                          |
        //                          +-- becomes "a" of the next iteration

        Node a = this.head, b, c;
        while ((b = a.getNext()) != null && (c = b.getNext()) != null) {
            Node d = c.getNext();
            a.setNext(c);
            c.setNext(b);
            b.setNext(d);
            a = b;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("[");
        for (Node n = this.head.getNext(); n != null; n = n.getNext()) {
            s.append(n);
            s.append(", ");
        }
        if (s.length() >= 2) s.setLength(s.length() - 2);   // Remove final ", "
        return s.append(']').toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code is clean and simple. As to `print()`, I totally forgot about `toString()`. You know... When you think of something complicated, you forget simple things.

Comment: About the two styles of linked lists. If I understand you correctly, [the first implementation style](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/43494/9357) doesn't contain two distinct classes: Node and LinkedList. There I personally would use the static method `makeList` rather than the constructor because the second parameter of the constructor contains is a `LinkedListNode` variable which should also be constructes, and, in its turn, contains its own `next` in its constructor. E.g., `LinkedListNode<Integer> linkedListNode = new LinkedListNode<Integer>(1, new LinkedListNode<Integer>(3, null));`

Comment: Thank you for the simplification suggestions. `fop` meant `the first in a pair`.

Comment: I posted [the third round](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/98120/23821) of code review.

Comment: Yes, I think you have understood me correctly.